# Что из себя представляет RIO Socket и как его можно использовать в .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет

Что из себя представляет `RIO Socket` и как его можно использовать в .NET для повышения производительности обычных сокетов\использования вместо обычных сокетов?

Я видел библиотеку `RioSharp`, но она заточена только под `Web`, и непонятно как оперировать отдельным сокетом.

Если возможно - приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный пример.

Comment: Судя по всему, имеется в виду вот это: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997032(v=ws.11).aspx. И вроде бы есть .NET-обёртка: https://github.com/aL3891/RioSharp